# Having an issue with my regex for accpeting dates of the format YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have a regex that I found through another post to validate dates in the format of YYYY-MM-DD: [12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[02])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]). I checked it on the website https://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html and it worked in every case I needed it to work, but on my own page it always returns false. Here is my code:

```js
function checkValues(uid, displayTitle, message, date) {
 var errList = document.getElementById("errors");
 errList.innerHTML = "";
 var errFound = false;
 var regex = new RegExp('[12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[02])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])');
 if (!date.match(regex)) {
  displayError("Date should follow the format: YYYY-MM-DD");
  errFound = true;
 }
 if (!errFound) {
  displayError("congrats");
 }
}
```

Is there some syntax error that I am missing here or is my regex wrong? Thanks in advance, and if you need more information let me know and I will update the post.

Comment: Hint: `1[02]` only allows 10 and 12, so 11, 13, etc. are invalid.

Comment: `[02]` should be `[012]`

Comment: @tadman `13` is supposed to be invalid, or have you heard of some new months being added?

Comment: @Barmar It's missing November and Splocktober.

Comment: BTW, don't use `new RegExp` unless you're creating the regexp dynamically. Use a RegExp literal.

Comment: @tadman I think you may have indulged in Slocktoberfest too much :)

Comment: `and it worked in every case I needed it to work` ... there is a minor but nasty edge case here, which is that February 29th only occurs once every four years.  Your regex pattern does not handle this scenario.  It would be best to use a date library within JavaScript rather than a regex.

Comment: @Barmar I added the change for [012] but it still fails for every single date I try (ex. 2019-10-31 fails). Do you think it could be some syntax error I'm not catching?

Comment: How about using `if(!date.match(/^[12]\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/))` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes in the string, so they'll be passed literally to the `RegExp` constructor.

This is why it's better to use a RegExp literal instead of `new RegExp` when you're not constructing the regexp dynamically.

```js
function checkValues(date) {
  var regex = new RegExp('[12]\\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12]\\d|3[01])');
  if (!date.match(regex)) {
    console.log("Date should follow the format: YYYY-MM-DD");
  } else {
    console.log("congrats");
  }
}

checkValues('2019-01-01');
checkValues('2019-11-21');
checkValues('2019-10-31');
checkValues('1234-56-78');
```